# Low-end triple monitor setup problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, eyefinity

I've just setup my triple monitor configuration here at work and am running into some snags with one of the monitors.

**The problem:**

Two of the monitors are identical, but one of these two (the one running off of the DisplayPort) is not reaching maximum resolution.

My primary monitor, connected via DVI, is set to 1680x1050.
The secondary monitor, connected via DisplayPort and adapter, cannot go beyond 1440x900.
The tertiary monitor, connected via VGA, is fine at 1024x768.

**Hardware used:**

- 2x Dell 2009w monitors
- Elo ET1529L monitor
- XFX ATI Radeon HD 5450 video card (HD545XZAF2)
- Accell B087B-005B UltraAV DisplayPort to DVI-D Single-Link Active Adapter

**Trouble-shooting:**

I've found that if I disconnect the tertiary monitor and connect the secondary via VGA it works fine at 1680x1050.  It is limited to 1440x900 connected via DisplayPort with or without the tertiary monitor.

Any ideas on how to get this second monitor at the correct resolution?  I'm wondering if it is my adapter.  I thought that the DisplayPort to DVI adapter was supposed to be ok up to 1920x1200.

Comment: A colleague of mine suggests that you're expecting a lot from that card, and that may be the problem.

Comment: I agree with Randolph but the one thing that comes to my mind is are all of your drivers as up to date as possible?

Comment: @Randolph: What is your colleague basing that on?  Does he or she have a link to support that claim?  I'm curious because XFX's site says the card supports three monitor output, but I can't find details on what resolutions are supported when all three outputs are in use.  (http://xfxforce.com/en-us/products/graphiccards/HD%205000series/5450.aspx)

@Frank: Yes, latest drivers from AMD have been installed.

Comment: @80bower - he's basing it on extensive experience. You may find that the max resolution is not supported for all three monitors.

Comment: @Randolph: While I appreciate the response, I'd like to see some data or a manufacturer's site to back up that claim.  No offense, but "my friend says" doesn't help me solve my problem.

Comment: @80bower, you asked if it was your adapter. My colleague seems to think it is. That is all.

Comment: if you can increase the resolution of the 2nd monitor by reducing the resolution of your 1st monitor then its a card limitation.

Comment: @Mohamed: I'll give that a shot tomorrow.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the DP adapter you have is not sufficient for the task. Is it on the [list](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx) of validated dongles?

Comment: Yes, it is the ninth one listed.